# Cumulant of functions of weakly dependent random variables

Tags: pr.probability, fourier-transform, moments, cumulants

Suppose $X_1,\dots,X_4$ are Gaussian random variables with mean and variance
$$\mathbf E X_i = 0,\quad \mathbf E X_i^2=1.$$
Furthermore suppose that the random variables have a certain weak correlation 
$$\mathbf E X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4=\kappa(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)=\epsilon,$$
but that all other joint cumulants $\kappa$ are at least $O(\epsilon^2)$. Note that in particular the random variables *cannot* be jointly Gaussian.

Now I am wondering whether something general can be said about the joint cumulant of $f(X_1),\dots,f(X_4)$ for well behaved functions $f$? As an example, it seems that for $f(x)=x^{2k-1}$ we have 
$$\kappa(X_1^{2k-1},\dots,X_4^{2k-1})=\epsilon (2k-1)!!^4 + O(\epsilon^2)$$
and 
$$\kappa(X_1^{2k},\dots,X_4^{2k})=O(\epsilon^2).$$ 
In light of this it seems natural to conjecture that 
$$\kappa(f(X_1),\dots, f(X_4)) = \epsilon\Bigl(\mathbf E_{X\sim N(0,1)} f'(X)\Bigr)^4+O(\epsilon^2)\tag{*}.$$

**Question:** Is (*) correct? If yes, can it be proved using something other than polynomial approximation?

Comment: May I ask for the reason of the down vote? Is this question too elementary for this site?